# '/users/insert' is already defined for second mongo database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have two dashboards under meteor, and I would like to list all the user accounts from both dashboards on one page.

I have found that connecting to a distant mongo is fairly easy :

```
var distantDatabase  = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor");
SecondDashboardUsers = new Mongo.Collection("users", { _driver: distantDatabase });
```

The only issue with this method is that I get an error since both databases are defined in the same way (for code consistancy) :

```
Error: A method named '/users/insert' is already defined
```

Is there a workarround, like an alias I could set to the collection?

Comment: As things are right now, I doubt this is doable without forking the `mongo` package. I can imagine a working solution that connects to 2 separate Meteor back-ends using DDP and using 1 "virtual" collection (a collection that is only defined on the client side), as 2 collections with the same name cannot be created even on the client side. I think that an adding an `alias` option when constructing a Collection is doable.